# How to disable catalog image scrolling in details page magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, gallery-image, fotorama-slider

> Actually in my case for details page base images scrolling is
>   available with mouse.we can scroll it but by looking wise it wont show
>   slider is available there.
>
> so i want to disable image scrolling which is coming using mouse hand
>   symbol if we over on image.

Comment: You mean have you disable magnifier ?

Comment: @KirtiNariya,no no i want to disable images scrolling like we can scroll banner.so thing is if we mouse over on image and move right or left one using hand symbol it is working like sliding images one by one that i want to disable in module/customthe/etc/view.xml